# Get array index of sender component in Delphi

Tags: delphi

When I have an array of, lets say, 20 components, that I create programmatically from the code, and I add the same onClick procedure to all of them, is there a way that I can get the component's array index via the Sender variable of the procedure?

I know I can access to other properties by (Sender as TComponentType).Property, but that's mostly all I can think of doing with the Sender variable.

Example:

```
var Button: array [0..9] of TButton;

for i := 0 to 9 do
  begin
    Button[i]:=TButton.Create(Self);
    Button[i].OnClick:=ButtonClick;
  end;


procedure ButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // Here I'd like to get the "i" of the sender Button[i]
end
```

Comment: Using arrays to contain controls is not a very smart idea. You should use something like a `TList` or `TList<TButton>` instead, or rely on owner or parent relationship of objects, depending on the purpose. What version of Delphi are you using?

Comment: What is the bad thing of using arrays?   What do you mean by "rely on owner or parent relationship of objects"...?  In my code the buttons have a form as a parent set actually, if that matters....  Using Delphi XE3

Comment: They don't allow flexibility as a generic `TList<>` does. Using a `TList` of any type will allow you to use an `IndexOf` function. But it highly depends on what version of Delphi you're using. By not relying on those relationships, and ditching any list/array, you could still manage those controls. But we don't know how you're actually using it, so it's hard to tell. The problem is your controls are already being managed in two places based on your code: 1) Standard VCL ownership, and 2) Your array.

Comment: But in any case, a `TList` of any sort provides an `IndexOf` function which returns the list index of any given matching object which it contains. That's what I interpret your question to be asking, anyway.

Comment: `for i := Low(Button) to High(Button) do if Button[i] = Sender then begin ...work with i... Break; end;` if you want to stay by array.

Comment: I'm actually using it in a way that I programmatically create additional buttons, depending on how many of them I need, and call the same procedure to show some data, indexed by the button (sender) index. that's pretty much it...

Comment: Thank yo for both solutions!
@TLama for the thing I was actually looking for, though I hoped it could be done without a for loop.  You should post this as an answer though..?

Comment: and @JerryDodge for another solution, which definitelly draw my attention to possible use, due to a few other functions that might come handy! Perfect.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, Tag property holds other integer info I need, so that's not an option. Should mention that in a question, probably...

Comment: @Just - Tag holds as much as you want, you can store a pointer to it. However that was not a very serious suggestion. A dictionary, list, iterating the array would do equally well.

Comment: A much easier solution is to use the button's tag property to store a value (such as the index), and then you can get to it by using `(Sender as TButton).Tag`. You don't even need an array that way.

Comment: Or you could use an intermediate object or record or other class of sort which contains this control as one of its members. There are many options here.

Comment: @Jerry: You say using an array is bad, and offer a solution that's much more complex (an intermediate object or record or other class). An array works fine, has less overhead than the other methods if all you need is a simple container, and if you use the control's `Tag` property you don't even have to search that array to locate the control.

Comment: @Ken It all depends on how OP is actually implementing it in the end, which we don't know. I'm just bringing light to things OP may not have though of before, to help in seeking new alternatives.

Comment: @Jerry: The OP has already said "I have an array", and asked how to locate a control within the array. I don't know what part of that isn't clear.

Comment: @Ken Forgive me for offering a variety of possible alternative approaches. Hence the comments instead of an answer. Speaking of which, why isn't TLama's comment an answer yet?

Comment: @Jerry: Viable alternatives would be better. :-) Good point about TLama's comment; he should make it an answer, as it's the appropriate solution. He has a tendency to do that, though; if he didn't, his rep would be considerably higher by now.

Comment: Thank you both for bringing other options and debate up. Some good thoughts came up while reading this... :)     For now I think I'll stick to array though, since its maximum number of elements is 200, so I dont expect any delays because of the for loop used, (though I know this isnt the best possible option). The reason for so is because I'm managing this array from several points of the application so it would take some not urgently necessary time to change all of them.. :) But I think TList could be really good alternative for future use!

Comment: Speaking of alternative solutions OP could go and make a decendant class from TButton which would contain aditional fields and properties to store and maintain any aditional data the OP requires. And the best thing about this approach is that OP could probably be able to retain most of his existing code.

Comment: @SilverWarior that is actually one of best possible solutions as well!  You should post this as an answer as well!

Comment: `TList` is just a wrapper for an array with some useful methods to work with (get the index of an item). The index is also resolved by a loop through the elements. There is no need for rewriting already written code. `CallByButton( FButtonList.IndexOf( Sender as TButton ) );`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Posting different answers as community wiki (no upvotes for me) for the sake of clarity, since no one wanted to post them for some weird reasons*

You can make a custom descendant from TButton and add your own field to it:

```
type
  TMyButton = class(TButton)
  public
    Tag2: Integer;
  end;

for i := 0 to 9 do
begin
  Button[i] := TMyButton.Create(Self);
  Button[i].OnClick := ButtonClick;
  Button[i].Tag2 := i;
end;

procedure ButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  // get the "i" of the sender Button from Tag
  i := TMyButton(Sender).Tag2;
end;
```

Comment: By far the most favorite answer I got so far, therefore I will accept this as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

*Posting different answers as community wiki (no upvotes for me) for the sake of clarity, since no one wanted to post them for some weird reasons*

You can use the `Tag` property like so:

```
for i := 0 to 9 do
begin
  Button[i] := TButton.Create(Self);
  Button[i].OnClick := ButtonClick;
  Button[i].Tag := i;
end;

procedure ButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  // get the "i" of the sender Button from Tag
  i := TButton(Sender).Tag;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but as already commented above, .Tag doesn't work for me as it is used for a different purpose. Hence the need for an alternate way of finding the sender. :)  But for some this might come in handy.

Answer (score 3):

*Posting different answers as community wiki (no upvotes for me) for the sake of clarity, since no one wanted to post them for some weird reasons*

You could iterate through Buttons, which is less "elegant" than Tags

```
for i := 0 to 9 do
begin
  Button[i] := TButton.Create(Self);
  Button[i].OnClick := ButtonClick;
end;

procedure ButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  i,j: Integer;
begin
  for j := 0 to 9 do
  if Button[j] = Sender then
    i := j;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks. Comment removed. FWIW, no need for CW here. If people choose to write comments instead of answers that's up to them. Questions are there to be answered. Feel free to answer them even if the same ideas have been floated in comments. It takes time to write answers. You took that time which should be applauded. No reason at all that you should not gain rep.

Comment: For the sake of simplicity I used this method in my existing code, though as said, not as elegant as other answers.
+, as David said - no reason you wouldn't gain rep for taking time to post answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
  public
  end;

type
  TMyButton = class(TButton)
  public
    Tag2: Integer;
  end;

var
   Button: array [0..9] of TMyButton;
   Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.ButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  i := TMyButton(Sender).Tag2;
  showmessage('Button['+inttostr(i)+'] : Nilai i dari Button[i] = '+inttostr(i));
end;

procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
var
   i : byte;
begin
   for i := 0 to 9 do
   begin
     Button[i] := TMyButton.Create(Form1);
     Button[i].Parent:= Form1;
     Button[i].OnClick := ButtonClick;
     Button[i].Tag2 := i;
     button[i].Top:=((button[i].Height+5)*i) + 10;
     Button[i].Left:=50;
     Button[i].Caption:='Button['+inttostr(i)+']';
   end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: I try to add or refine the answer given by @Kromster, where the answer is almost correct, there's just a less code that it could make error when running the program. I think the following code should be adde after button created :
    Button[i].Parent:= Form1;
I add the above code and try to appear on the form without any error when runing